# String inside {{ }} as Interpolation Code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The `FormControlNames` of my elements are generated dynamicly this way: `id{{foo.foo_id}}{{bar.bar_id}}{{bob.bob_id}}`

The result is something like `id137`.

When I now use `{{form.controls.id137.status}}`, in the `HTML`, I get `VALID / INVALID` like it should.

But when I do `{{'form.controls.id' + foo.foo_id + bar.bar_id + bob.bob_id + '.status'}}` I just get the line `form.controls.id137.status` on my page as a string, but it is not actually run.

How can I make `Angular` run this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
{{ form.get('id'+foo.foo_id + '' + bar.bar_id + '' + bob.bob_id)?.status }}
```

or

```
{{ form.controls['id'+foo.foo_id + '' + bar.bar_id + '' + bob.bob_id]?.status }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a string when you add quotes around 'form.controls.id' and '.status'

Try something like:

`{{ form.get('id' + foo.foo_id + bar.bar_id + bob.bob_id)?.status }}`

Comment: @igor_c if ids are number, then your original code wasn't working, since you added some numbers, your edit is correct

Comment: yes, that's why I added 'id' to my id's.
not working: id="137"; working: id="id137"